# Vue Router - Default value for optional url parameter when a separate optional url parameter is set

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have the following route:

```
export const personRoutes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  {
    path: '/person/:id?/:handedSlug?',
    name: 'Person',
    component: () => import('./view/person'),
  },
];
```

I have a method that takes filters and updates the route:

```
updateRoute(): void {
  const filters = this.filters;
  const router = this.$router;
  router.push({
    name: 'Person',
    params: {
      id: filters.getId(),
      handedSlug: filters.handedSlug(),
    },
  });
},
```

The trouble I am running into, is if id is null, and handed is set, the returned URL is: `person/handedValue`, when what I need is `person/all/handedValue`.

How does one go about setting a default property for an optional parameter, if a later parameter in the URL is set?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way, but if there was then it couldn't be considered optional. I suggest simply passing in the string 'all' if `filters.getId()` is null

```js
updateRoute(): void {
  const filters = this.filters;
  const router = this.$router;

  let routeId = filters.getId()
  if (!routeId && filters.handedSlug()) {
    routeId = 'all'
  }

  router.push({
    name: 'Person',
    params: {
      id: routeId,
      handedSlug: filters.handedSlug(),
    },
  });
},
```